# Total Coloring of even regular bipartite graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

Consider an even order, balanced(both partitions have same vertices) bipartite regular graph of order greater than or equal to $12$ and degree atleast six and divisible by $6$. Then is the graph of Type 1(totally colorable by $\Delta+1$ colors where $\Delta$ is the maximum degree)?

By petersen theorem, the graph has 2-factor( in fact k-factors for $k\le2n$, where $2n$ be the total number of vertices). Again, it is a union of disjoint $1$ factors(perfect matchings).Could these be used to provide a total coloring?

Apart from this, since the degree is also divisible by $3$(i.e. divisible by $6$), then, we may be able to find cycles of order divisible by $3$($6$); and since cycles whose order is divisible by $3$ can be totally colored(each pair of adjacent or incident elements of graph receive different colors) with $3$ colors, therefore we can also totally color each disjoint cycle in the graph using just three colors. Can we use this fact to totally color the whole graph with ($\Delta+1$) colors?

Comment: how the order of cycles is connected to the degrees?

Comment: @FedorPetrov edited the question slightly. Please read now.

Comment: Still not clear at all.

Comment: @FedorPetrov could you please tell exactly where you found the question doubtful? Again edited

Comment: "We may be able to find" - how?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Actually, I took my inspiration from the connected Cayley graph of a symmetric group with transpositions as generating set. In that graph, I start from one vertex(identity) and traverse to transposition element, then to elements of the form of product of two transpositions and so on, reaching back to identity, which is an even cycle divisible by $6$ provided the group is symmetric on atleast $4$ symbols. May be, I am using vertex transitive property here?

Comment: A. Is the graph regular, or is the only requirement that every vertex has degree divisible by 3. B. And I am not seeing why the requirement that each vertex has degree divisible by 3 and at least 6, implies that each vertex has degree divisble by 6.

Comment: @Mike yes, the question I wrote clearly mentioned regular

Comment: Indeed @vidyarthi you did mention that just saw it. But what if every vertex has degree 9 say.

Comment: @Mike oh! sorry, again edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not always possible to total color a bipartite graph with $\Delta+1$ colors, even with the given restrictions on $\Delta$ and the number of vertices. This is a counterexample. Let $G$ be a complete bipartite graph with $n$ vertices on each side, where $n$ can be any integer you want as long as it is sufficiently large. [So the degree of each vertex is $n$.]

Suppose there were a proper total coloring $\chi$ using only $n+1$ colors, Let $X$ and $Y$ be the parts of $G$ [to be clear $X$ and $Y$ are sets of vertices], and let $X_{n+1}$ be the entire subset of $X$ that is colored with the $(n+1)$-st colour by $\chi$, and assume WLOG that $X_{n+1}$ is nonempty. Next, let $E_{n+1}$ be the subset of edges colored with the $(n+1)$-st color by this proper total coloring $\chi$. Then $E_{n+1}$ is a matching of cardinality $|X|-|X_{n+1}|=|Y|-|X_{n+1}| < |Y|$. So let $U$ be a subset of $Y$ not incident to an edge in $E_{n+1}$. Then as $G$ is a complete graph, every vertex in $U$ is adjacent to a vertex in $X_{n+1}$, so no vertex in $U$ can 
be colored with the $(n+1)$st color, and furthermore, as every vertex in $U$ is also not incident to an edge in $E_{n+1}$, it follows that for each $u \in U$ there are only $n$ colors to color $u$ and its $n$ edges incident to $U$ with all different colors. This is impossible.

Comment: thanks! I thought about it and am now thinking that this is true of every regular bipartite graphs also. What is your opinion? Any counterexample, i.e., any regular bipartite graph of type $1$?

Comment: Well, admittedly my above argument does not carry through if $d<<n$, where  $d$ is defined to be the degree and $n$ the number of vertices on each side. In that case $X_{n+1}$ can have only $\lceil \frac{n}{d+1} \rceil d$ neighbours on the other side. If $n=d$ then  $\lceil \frac{n}{d+1} \rceil d$ is of course $n$.

Comment: First, by König theorem, every bipartite graph has edge coloring using $\Delta$ colors where $\Delta$ is maximum degree. Now, consider any vertex. Since $\Delta$ colors are used, so we have to use at least one new color. Again, let the graph be regular. Then, any vertex adjacent to the above chosen vertex should also get another color distinct from $\Delta+1$ colors for a total coloring. Hence, we require $\Delta+2$ colors for a total coloring. Is this argument ok?

Comment: Well, suppose $v$ is colored $d+1$ and let $w$ be a neighbor of $v$. Then a priori at least $w$ is allowed to be colored any color besides $d+1$ and the color assigned to the edge $vw$

Comment: but, what about the edges incident to the vertex $w$? I am talking about regular bipartite here

Comment: Well, I think an infinite k-ary tree can be totally colored w only k+1 colors. So we do have more work to do

Comment: But, what about finite case?

Comment: I will have to think about it some more. On the one hand I am sure (come to think about it) that my argument can be extended for *most* d-regular bipartite graphs w n vertices on each side $d$ and $n$ can be whatever you choose. On the other hand, I think I can come up with such a graph that is $d+1$-totally coverable.

Comment: sorry, you meant colorable?

Comment: yes colorable....

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile for fixed e.g, $d=6$ there are infinite families of $d$-regular bipartite graphs that have a total coloring with $d+1$ (here 7) colors.

Let $X=\{x_0,\ldots, x_{n-1} \}$ and let $Y = \{y_0,\ldots, x_{n-1}\}$, where $n$ is a multiple of 42.

Then $x_j$ and $y_{j'}$ are adjacent if $j-j' \in \{-3,-2,-1,1,2,3\}$ arithmetic done mod $n$.

The colors are the set $\mathbb{F}_7$; the edge $x_jy_{j'}$ is colored $j+j'$ mod 7, while the vertices $y_j$ and $x_j$ are each colored $2j$ mod 7

Comment: great and thanks! But, now, this gives rise to another question. Whether we require $n$ to be a multiple of $42$(or $d(d+1)$) or anything lower is sufficient?

Comment: I think the above construction works for $n=7$ also